# search pattern between known string and unknown decimal number which are in diffrent line number

Tags: shell, awk, sed, scripting

I want to search pattern between a known string and unknown decimal number which is in different line in a file.

Suppose we have to search a pattern and replace with another pattern in same file :

Ex. file contains below contents :

```
###line 1..
###line 2..
###line 3..
known_string 
###line 5
###line 6
4444
###line 8
###line 9
###line 10
unknown_string 
###line 11
###line 12
6666
unknown_string 
###line 15
###line 16
5555
EOF
```

In the above example, I have to search a pattern from file.

```
known_string
###line 5
###line 6
4444
```

and have to replace with another pattern in same file :

```
known_string 
###line 5
###line 6
8850
```

So, the output should be in below format :

```
###line 1..
###line 2..
###line 3..
known_string 
###line 5
###line 6
8850
###line 8
###line 9
###line 10
unknown_string 
###line 11
###line 12
6666
unknown_string 
###line 15
###line 16
5555
EOF
```

I have tried using "sed" command,

```
sed -i -e '/known_sting/{p:d;};N;N;N;c; 'known_string'N;'8850'' filename
```

But not getting the desired result.

Thanks.

Comment: sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines, that is all. If you are using sed commands other than s, g, and p (with -n) then you are using the wrong tool as all the other sed constructs became obsolete in the mid-1970s when awk was invented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easier with `awk`:

```
awk '/^[ \t]*known_string/{p=1} p && $0+0==$0{$0="8850"; p=0} 1' file

###line 1..
###line 2..
###line 3..
known_string
###line 5
###line 6
8850
###line 8
###line 9
###line 10
unknown_string
###line 11
###line 12
6666
unknown_string
###line 15
###line 16
5555
EOF
```

- `/^known_string/{p=1}` will set a flag when `known_string` is found at start.
- `$0+0==$0` check is to ensure current line is a valid number.
- `p=0` will reset the flag.

Comment: thanks for response, It's working for the example given above, but it's also replacing decimal value with below any unknown string.

Comment: it's also replacing the decimal value in ex. given below :
###line 1..
###line 2..
###line 3..
known_string
###line 5
###line 6
8850
###line 8
###line 9
###line 10
unknown_string
###line 12
###line 13
8850
###line 15
EOF

Comment: I have to replace only decimal number i.e just below the known string, after that no replacement is required.

Comment: What do you mean by nothing, did you see updated output which is same as your expected output. Difference is extra `p=0` in 2nd block.

Comment: Means it's not updating the decimal value, just after the known string.

Comment: To update input file using gnu awk use: `awk -i inplace '/^known_string/{p=1} p && $0+0==$0{$0="8850"; p=0} 1' file`. If NOT using gnu awk then `awk '/^known_string/{p=1} p && $0+0==$0{$0="8850"; p=0} 1' file > _file.tmp && mv _file.tmp file`

Comment: fyi `8850` is appearing in output as you've shown in question.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but I am getting the desired output

Comment: You are getting or not getting desired output?

Comment: I am not getting the desired output, the decimal value "4444" is not getting updated to "8850" below the known string.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120784/discussion-between-anubhava-and-harsh-pratap).